# Double Hodge star proof

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

I'm having some trouble understanding the proof of acting the Hodge star operator twice on some p-form. Specifically, I don't understand how they went from the first line to the second one. The rest is ok. I see that the indices in the second Levi-Civita tensor went from left to right and vice-versa but what does that mean exactly? I know the contraction formula for contracting some $p$ indices but I don't understand how to get to that result.

[image]

Comment: *The indices in the second Levi-Civita tensor went from left to right and vice-versa but what does that mean exactly?* They used the antisymmetry of $\epsilon$ to move them.

Comment: Oh god, of course... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The authors of your text were careless.

Both  inverse factorials should have been carried onto the second line. The $1/(n-p)!$ then gets cancelled by the sum over the  $(n-p)!$ orderings of the sum over $\sigma$'s when  passing from the second to the third. The remaining $1/n!$ cancels with  the $n!$ orderings of the sum over the  $\nu$'s  in passing from the third to fourth line.