# Why does the Hodge star operator applied twice pick up a sign relating to the eigenvalues of the metric

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

Sean Carroll's notes state that given a $p$ form $A$ in an $n$-dim manifold, we find that the Hodge star applied twice yields

$**A = (-1)^{s+p(n-p)}A$

where "s is the number of minus signs in the eigenvalues of the metric (for Minkowski space,
s = 1)"

Doing my own derivation, it is straightforward to recover the factor of $(-1)^{p(n-p)}$, and I can see that the eigenvalues of the metric are hidden in the definition of the Levi-Civita *tensor* as opposed to the Levi-Civita *symbol*. Again in Carroll's notation, the Levi-Civita *tensor* is defined

$\epsilon_{\mu_1...\mu_p} = \sqrt{|g|}\tilde{\epsilon}_{\mu_1...\mu_p}$

where $\tilde{\epsilon}_{\mu_1...\mu_p}$ is defined as the Levi-Civita *symbol* in the usual way regardless of coordinate system and therefore not a tensor, and $g = \det(g_{\mu\nu})$. Since the determinant can be computed as the product of its eigenvalues, I can see where eigenvalues of the metric appear. However, since there's an absolute value sign wrapped around it, it seems like it should not contribute a minus sign. Furthermore the absolute value is there for a good reason, e.g. the Jacobian for change of basis should be positive to preserve orientation. So I'm not sure where this $(-1)^s$ factor comes from.

Note: the computation is also carried out in this [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/743117/double-hodge-star-proof), however this $(-1)^s$ factor just appears without explanation and is not helpful for my question.

Comment: First suppose $\{\lambda^1,\dots, \lambda^n\}$ is an orthonormal (relative to $g$) collection of covectors. Can you calculate what the Hodge star of a wedge of them is, i.e what is $\star(\lambda^I)$, where $\lambda^I:=\lambda^{i_1}\wedge \cdots\wedge\lambda^{i_k}$? Or even simpler, work out what exactly the Hodge star of $\lambda^1$ is.

Comment: Using Carroll's notation, 
$(*\lambda^1)_{\mu_1...\mu_{n-1}} = \epsilon^{\nu_1}_{\mu_1...\mu_{n-1}}\lambda_{\nu_1}^1$ and we can make the (inverse) metric explicit:
$(*\lambda^1)_{\mu_1...\mu_{n-1}} = \lambda_{\nu_1}^1 g^{\nu_1\mu_0}\epsilon_{\mu_0\mu_1...\mu_{n-1}}$. I can see that because of the signature of the metric, if $g_{\mu\nu}$ was just Minkowski for example there would be a minus sign picked up for $\mu_0 = \nu_1 = 0$ that isn't present when $\mu_0 = \nu_1 = 1,2,3$. However I'm struggling to formalize this into a $(-1)^s$.

Comment: Ok that answers my second question, now what about the first? How many minus signs do we pick up there?

Comment: Actually wait, even before moving on, simplify your answer. What are the various indices going to turn out to?